# Can the Hamburger moment problem be solved for probability measures?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, probability-theory

The hamburger moment problem states that given any real sequence $\{a_n\}$, there exists a positive Borel measure $\mu$ such that 
$$
a_n =\int_{\mathbb{R}} x^{n}\,d\mu.
$$
In other words, the sequence $\{a_n\}$ is the sequence of moments for some positive Borel measure.

My question is, can the hamburger moment problem be solved with the additional restriction that $\mu$ be a probability measure?

Comment: According to Wikipedia (http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamburger_moment_problem), the problem can **not** be solved for arbitrary sequences $(a_n)$, but additional assumptions have to be placed. The article also states that the solution is unique under certain assumptions. In this case, one can construct a sequence such that the resulting measure can **not** be a probability measure (simply take any sequence for which the solution is unique and multiply all coefficients by a common constant).

Comment: [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/3525/when-are-probability-distributions-completely-determined-by-their-moments) is a related question on mathoverflow

Comment: An obvious restriction is $a_{0}=1$. So, no, you can't do this for arbitrary sequences.